# Stop / start storyboard animation based on Visibility

Tags: wpf, silverlight, animation, eventtrigger

I have an animation that currently starts when a `Control` is loaded (the animation is essentially a waiting spinner, that is applied to an empty `ContentControl`).

The animation however will constantly spin taking up resources.  What I'd like is for the animation to start / stop based on whether the animation control is visible or not, is this possible?

```
<Canvas.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContentControl.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetName="SpinnerRotate"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01.3"
                RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Canvas.Triggers>
```

I must have this working for both Silverlight and WPF.

Comment: Are you looking only for XAML-way of doing this? The alternative would be to stop the animation in code-behind - you just need to give your Storyboard a x:Name

Comment: XAML would be neatest if possible?

Answer (score 7):

I have created an example of spinning an `Ellipse` based on the `Visibility` property. Perhaps you can use something from this.

```
 <Canvas>
    <Ellipse x:Name="Circle" Width="30" Height="30"
             Canvas.Left="50"
             Canvas.Top="50">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinnerRotate" CenterX="15" CenterY="15"/>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="SpinStoryboard">
                                <Storyboard >
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle"
                                                     From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:01.3"
                                                     RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="SpinStoryboard"></StopStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Ellipse.Style>
    </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Would this still work if the parent `Canvas` was not visible?

Comment: This answer works, but be aware of a catch. Making a parent control invisible (hidden/collapsed) will make the spinner shape (the ellipse in the code example) also disappear _without_ setting its visibility property, so the triggers won't fire and the animation will continue (eating CPU) without being visible. In order to actually stop the animation you have to make sure to set the visibility of the spinner shape directly or by binding it to the appropriate parent control (the one whose visibility will be changed).

Answer (score 4):

Might not be elegant, but works.

```
<Border x:Name="square" Height="20" Width="20" Background="Aqua">
        <Border.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="spinner">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                            Storyboard.TargetName="square"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:01.3"
                            AutoReverse="True"
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <Border.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Visibility}" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="spinner"/>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Style>
    </Border>
```

Comment: This looks promising - How do I make it start the storyboard on `Visible`

Comment: Add DataTrigger.ExitAction with `BeginStoryboard` (sorry, I'm not near my dev computer to try it out)... actually, I would reverse it... check for Visibility.Visible to BeginStoryboard on "enter" and Stop - on "exit"