# Defining a Path in a User Control throws compilation error: XDG0012 The member "Loaded" is not recognized or not accessible

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5, resourcedictionary

I had a dictionary.xaml where I defined the path specified here but I was having compilation error (see error below).

As I want to reuse it in other places, @Clemens suggested me to put it in an WPF UserControl, so I did it but I continue having below error, RoutedEvent Loaded is not recognized.

```
<UserControl x:Class="my.UI.UC.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://chemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <Path x:Name="SpinnerPath" Data="M100,10 A90,90 0 0 1 190,100"
              Width="24" Height="24"
              Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="20"
              StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform />
            </Path.RenderTransform>
            <Path.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle">
                            <DoubleAnimation By="360" 
                                             Duration="0:0:1"
                                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Path.Triggers>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The compiler throws a compilation error:

> XDG0012 The member "Loaded" is not recognized or not accessible

Am I missing a reference to some namespace in my dictionary? If so, what namespace?

Comment: Can you explain why you want that Path to be a XAML resource?

Comment: @Clemens I'll do. Now I am trying to define your path within a dictionary.xaml and then binding it to the view. Now I will see if that works and I put as accepted your answer in my another question.

Comment: That is not an explanation. You do usually not declare UI elements as XAML resources.

Comment: @Clemens because depending on the circumstances I want to show the path or not. Then programatically I am going to set it to null or binding it to the static resource.

Comment: You may have the Geometry (the Data) as resource. Load it like `Data="{DynamicResource myArc}"` or so.

Comment: @Clemens I would like to reuse that path across all my wpf windows. This is the reason.

Comment: Put it in a UserControl.

Comment: @Clemens In a WPF UserControl? Uhmm that sounds really good!

Comment: @Clemens I have put it within a WPF user control and I get the same error. Loaded event not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep the size of the Path, otherwise Data and StrokeThickness would not fit.

Put the Path in a Viewbox, and set the Width and Height of the UserControl.

```
<UserControl x:Class="my.UI.UC.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Width="24" Height="24">
    <Viewbox>
        <Path Data="M100,10 A90,90 0 0 1 190,100"
              Width="200" Height="200" Stretch="None"
              Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="20"
              StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform />
            </Path.RenderTransform>
            <Path.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="LoadedStoryboard">
                        <Storyboard TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Angle">
                            <DoubleAnimation By="360" Duration="0:0:1"
                                             RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unloaded">
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="LoadedStoryboard"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Path.Triggers>
        </Path>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: So as I see the RoutedEvent Loaded is recognized within a Viewbox. Could you explain me why? Also the height and width of the Path must always be the same as, greater than or less than the height and width of the UserControl?

Comment: The event is also recognized with any other container. The Path was just not visible.

Comment: This is another question but... in order to stop it eating resources doing animation when the usercontrol is not visible, is there any easy way to stop animation when it is not visible?

Comment: The Path must be large enough to show an unstretched Geometry. Any stretching will loose the center point and thus distort the rotation.

Comment: When the UserControl is not visible, the Loaded event will not fire.

Comment: Ok so imagine I make the UserControl visible (which it is inside of another UserControl) and animation starts. Later if I make this UserControl  not visible, I guess it will stop the animation automatically. Am I right then?

Comment: See the edit for an Unloaded EventTrigger. For the Visibility, use a Trigger in a Path Style.

Comment: And probably get a WPF book, where you can read about all those things. I can recommend *WPF Unleashed* by Adam Nathan.

Comment: So then when the UserControl is made not visible (after showing it), then the trigger Unloaded is executed, so the storyboard is stopped and not eating resources anymore. Right? Thx for all your help.

Comment: Regarding visibility there is an example here that does the same more or less:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575345/1624552